# Distributions, basic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis

Define

$g(x) = \frac{1}{2 \lambda} \exp(-\lambda\vert x\vert)$ for $\lambda >0$.

We want to show that

$-\partial^2_{xx}g+\lambda^2 g = \delta_0$

holds in order to show

$-u_{xx} + \lambda^2u = f$

for $f$ be a continuous bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is the problem above a famous problem? I am very thankful for any suggestions in order to prove the assertion!

Comment: This is an ODE, not a PDE.  Have you tried a simple case, e.g. take $\lambda = 1$ and evaluate $g(x)$ and $\partial_{xx} g(x)$ for $x > 0$ and for $x < 0$?

Comment: Yes I tried this, but $g(x)$ has a kink at $0$ which I do not know to handle with

Comment: What does it mean to solve an equation with a $\delta$ function? Do you have a notion of test functions?

Comment: @tubmaster, what Matt said (I would recommend the book by Kolmogorov and Fomin), and also consider the possibility of using the Laplace transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms

Comment: sorry, but I do not know what to do... do you have any suggestions or BuzzWords?

Answer (score 0):

What it would mean in this context is that
$$
          ``\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (-g_{xx}+\lambda g)fdx"
    = ``\int \delta_{0}(x)f(x)dx " = f(0),
$$
where $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and non-zero out side a finite interval. Then the integral on the left might is interpreted as the integral obtained by symbol integration by parts:
$$
              \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(-f_{xx}+\lambda f)dx = f(0)
$$
Now there is no problem with the existence of the expressions; $f$ is infinitely smooth, and $g$ integrates against $-f_{xx}+\lambda f$. So the above equation is what you need to verify. To verify this, break the integral into one part over $(-\infty,0]$ and the other over $[0,\infty)$. By splitting the integral, it is possible to actually integrate by parts, and if you keep track of the evaluation terms at $0$, you end up with $f(0)$, as desired.